# how to provision .ipa bulit by friend?

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

My friend has built an app (we both have developer accounts) I have the `.ipa` to test.

How can I provision the app onto my device ?

Do I have to rebuild from the source with my prov profile? or

Can I just send the `.ipa` to one of my test devices, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I provision the app onto my device ?

If you simply want to test on your `iPhone/iPad` Device, you just have to Create `Provisioning profile` with the Device ID (on which you want to test your app) and `.ipa file` and add them to your Device.

> Do I have to rebuild from the source with my prov profile? or

**No, just no.** There is no need to do so.

> Can I just send the .ipa to one of my test devices, if so how?

If you want to send it to your Testers located in different geo-graphic area then you can always use [**TestFlight**](https://testflightapp.com/).

It's a beautiful tool to send your beta apps over the air with ease. It's simple, painless, and magical. It provides app management, distribution, tracking, and centralized feedback as well as crash reporting.

You can integrate it in your App easily by following the steps given here : [**How to use TestFlight to distribute your beta app ?**](http://changhoward.blogspot.in/2012/02/ios-developer-how-to-use-testflight-to.html)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, so there is no way for me to provision this .ipa he built to my device? I'd have to send my test device details to him to add to his portal and have him rebuild OR send me the source and build myself is that correct?

Comment: @JohnWoods: I have added details in my answer. Check it. You just have to create Provisioning Profile and .ipa and sync them with your iPhone/iPad device.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm not being 100% clear, Testflight is great, but right now with just the .ipa built by him with his provisioning profile and without my on his device list is it possible for me to resign this ipa so I can use it right now?

Comment: @JohnWoods No, your device must be added to the Provisioning Profile. And If you get your Answer then you should accept it. :)

Comment: I actually did need to resign with my ad hoc profile to get this to work using $ codesign -s my\ certificates\ name example.ipa 

$ codesign -vv example.ipa
example.ipa: valid on disk
example.ipa: satisfies its Designated Requirement

Comment: @JohnWoods: What are you saying ? I am not getting you.